# upgrading org version8 export-block to org version9

Tags: org-export

I have been trying org-export with ox-trac for trac wiki format but ox-trac was developed for org version 8.x and I am running org version 9. Given that `:export-block` is obsolete now, so the export fails.  I have opened an issue on the ox-trac github development page but it appears that the development has ceased.
I am willing to upgrade it to v9, please help with some pointers to begin with.

Comment: "export fails" is vey little information to help you fix the problem.  Please describe very precisely *how* it fails.

Comment: The error it throws: `org-export-define-derived-backend: Unknown keyword: :export-block
`
Here is the [ox-trac.el](https://github.com/JalapenoGremlin/ox-trac/blob/master/ox-trac.el), please see line:89 and line:150
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ox-trac has been [fixed](https://github.com/JalapenoGremlin/ox-trac/commit/5ac6c81bbc18db6c17e267d6399778c3fb5bf1ee) by the developer for org version 9.